# Rails - storing values in join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, simple-form

I am trying to store client_id in join table: clients_orders after submitting the form below.

I set the tables in this way so I can look up all the orders a client has made. 
I am using rails 4 with devise and simple form.

## models

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 #has_and_belongs_to_many :clients
 belongs_to :clients #solution
end
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
 #has_and_belongs_to_many :orders
 as_many :orders, dependent: :destroy #solution
end
```

## orders form

```
<%= simple_form_for(@order) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

    <%= f.association :client, collection: Client.all, label_method: :name, value_method: :id, prompt: "Choose a Client" } %>
    <%= etc... %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

with the current code above, the join table clients_orders does not update

```
  create_table "clients_orders", id: false, force: true do |t|
    t.integer "client_id"
    t.integer "order_id"
  end
```

## order controller

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

  # GET /orders/new
  def new
    @order = Order.new
  end

  # POST /orders
  # POST /orders.json
  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    @order.user_id = current_user.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @order }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def order_params
      params.require(:order).permit(:code, :client_id, :user_id, :memo, :status, items_attributes: [:id, :name, :_destroy])
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future reference:

this is a simple one-to-many relationship. All you have to do to access a client's orders is to set up the `has_many :orders` in the **User** model and `belongs_to :user` in **Order** model. Then you can use collection methods like current_user.orders and it will get all of that specific user's orders for you. Just assign it to the user with `@order = current_user.orders.build(:order_params)`

Comment: but in my case I am not using the users model but instead I am using clients, so as @JamesMason said that I can leave the controller code I have with using the relations you mentioned between orders and clients (instead of user).

Answer (score 2):

You aren't whitelisting the correct parameters in your `create` action.

When dealing with has_and_belongs_to_many associations, you're dealing with *multiple* objects on each side, so the attributes you're whitelisting are plural, not singular.

You need to be whitelisting `client_ids`, not `client_id`.

Also, I'm pretty sure your form is wrong. You have it setup as though `client` is a has_one relationship. I think you want the plural version there as well.

```
<%= f.association :clients, #...
#                        ^----- add an 's'
```

If you really intended for the form to model a singular relationship, then you'll need to massage the data somewhere before saving your model. Here's one way to do it:

```
def create
  @order = Order.new(order_params)
  @order.client_ids << params[:order][:client_id]
  @order.user_id = current_user.id

  # save and respond...
end
```

If you go this route, then just remove `:client_id` from your parameters whitelist rather than pluralizing it.

Comment: I have added the orders controller

Comment: You need to whitelist `client_ids`, not `client_id`. See updated answer.

Comment: to clarify, my order form will register only one client but somewhere else in the application, if I look up a client, I want to see all the orders they made.

In this case would my models be wrong to define has_and_belongs_to_many associations

Comment: That makes sense. I added an example for how to pass the data from your form to the model.

Comment: in that case, i don't think you need HABTM relationship. A client `has_many` orders and and order `belongs_to` a client. Or am i missing something?

Comment: @Anchor I am not so sure myself. If removing the HABTM relationship and using the has_many and belongs_to will equate to just using two tables then perhaps that won't do since I need to have one client with a unique id having many orders. so I won't be able to save all the orders into one row. Hence I will need an additional table. All in all I am not sure if anything but the HABTM can provide that with my little experience on this subject.

Comment: to me it sounds like its a simple one-to-many relationship. All you'd have to do to access a client's orders is to set up the `has_many :orders` in the User model and `belongs_to :user` in order. Then you can use collection methods like current_user.orders and it will get all that user's order for you. Just assign it to the user with `@order = current_user.orders.build(:order_params)`

Comment: @Anchor, I will change the relationship to has_many :orders in clients and belongs to :clients in orders model since in this case it would be between orders and clients but then would I need the join table clients_orders?

Comment: @JamesMason I receive an error in the form while adding the s for whitelisting and the [@orders.client_ids ...] error: Association :clients not found

Comment: Orders don't exist independently from clients, so you don't need a separate table. Orders is, effectively, clients_orders.

Comment: If you change the associations as @Anchor suggested, then you can ignore everything in my answer. Your original code should all work as-is.

Comment: I am testing both still, trying to figure this out. Will post update in a bit.

Comment: @lightbots good luck :) you'd only need a join table if you want to be able to find all clients associated with an order, i.e: `@order.clients`

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I have used @Anchor suggestion. You can create a separate answer if you would like.

Comment: @JamesMason I am new to RoR and did not understand fully some of the things you have mentioned. If you have time can you explain what the following code means: `params[:order][:client_id]` in `@order.client_ids << params[:order][:client_id]`

Comment: @lightbots that's the direct way to access to request parameters. It's basically the same thing as your `order_params` method, but without the whitelisting. You should **always** use the whitelisting method when accessing multiple parameters at once, but it's not necessary when accessing a single parameter. I'm sure this has been answered in more detail on here somewhere, too :).